# regex attribute not working in xsl:analyze-string function

Tags: xml, regex, xslt, xpath

The given source xml is part is `<EORI_Number>23 March 2002</EORI_Number>`

and applying style sheet that given below

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="EORI_Number" regex=".*([0-9]+)\s+([A-Z](a-z)+)\s+([0-9]+).*">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
    one        
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    two
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

Its not working. I am a beginner in `xslt` so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've downvoted the question because it's not well constructed. Don't tell us something "doesn't work". Tell us what input you supplied and what output you got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because your regex is incorrect. Try this:

```
.*([0-9]+)\s+([A-Z][a-z]+)\s+([0-9]+).*
```

**Note**: Changed `(a-z)` to `[a-z]` from original regex.